# Actualización de div mediante JQUERY y AJAX no funciona en servidor linux, si en XAMPP local

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, linux, xampp

tengo una aplicación (panel de carga de unagebes para unaa web) que localmente, utilizando xampp, funciona sin problema, pero al subirlo al servidor (en linux, de Nuthost) me tira error 500. He probado modificando el archivo llamado para que solo devuelva una cadena de texto corta y funciona bien, pero al intentar devolver una tabla con los datos de las imagenes cargadas en la web, tira el mencionado error.

Dejo el codigo del llamado al archivo.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var ordenado = '<?= $ordenarpor ?>';
load_orden(1, ordenado);
});


function load_orden(page, orden) {
var q = $("#q").val();
$("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
$.ajax({
    url: '../ajax/buscar_s_principal.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {action: "ajax", page: page, q: q, orden: orden},
    beforeSend: function (objeto) {
        $('#loader').html('<img src="../img/ajax-loader.gif">');
        alert("before");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        $('#loader').html('');
    }
});
}
```

Al cargar la pagina se ejecuta el load_orden donde se llama al archivo buscar_s_principal.php donde conecta a la base de datos y devuelve una tabla en html que es lo que se asigna al outer_div.
El alert en el before se ejecuta siempre, el alert en el success solo si modifico el archivo buscar_s_principal.php con algo con algo como testeando.

En la pagina hay un boton de carga que abre un modal y hace el grabado en la base mediante ajax y esa parte funciona correctamente.

Espero haber sido claro, gracias desde ya por la ayuda.

**Editado:**

Incluí ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL); como me indicaron pero no muestra ningun error. Solamente en la consola aparece Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

**Editado 2:**
Gracias por la respuesta, aclaro que en el servidor esta instalada la version 7.2 de php, y esta en este momento funcionando una web en wordpress ademas de una tienda online. De todas formas otros llamados a ajax me funcionaron sin problema (por ejemplo funciona la carga de nuevas imagenes grabando en la base de datos). Solo con este me tira el error 500 y parece ser por el tamaño de la respuesta de ajax, ya que funciona bien si devuelvo una string corta.

Este mismo panel (con minimas diferencias) esta funcionando en otros servidores con esa version de php o con php7.4 si bien la version que tengo instalada local es php8.

No se si hay alguna configuración diferente que pueda solicitar al hosting modificar, no tengo acceso al archivo de configuración de apache en el servidor, ni tampoco al de PHP completo.

Comment: Revisa el log de errores, o pon estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script PHP: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`, guarda, ejecuta de nuevo y agrega a la pregunta los mensajes de error que veas. Ten en cuenta que en tu nuevo contexto debes tener todo a punto para que funcione: base de datos, credenciales, archivos, etc.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de `buscar_s_principal.php` y, como ya te sugirieron, revisa el log de errores, copia y pega las últimas líneas. En cuanto a `ini_set()`, algunos servidores no permiten su uso, ya sea para evitar riesgos o consumo excesivo de recursos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré el problema.

Al subir el archivo `buscar_s_principal.php`, el servidor **lo comprimía borrándole los espacios**, quedaba todo en una linea y todo junto. Pude subirlo sin que pase esto y no hubo más problema.